# Import property without using typeof in dnlib

Tags: .net, dnlib

could you help, please? To add the following line to the target assembly:
`this._startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;`
I use the following code to import the UtcNow property:
`var utcNowMethodInfo = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty(nameof(DateTime.UtcNow)).GetGetMethod();`
`var utcNow = moduleDefMD.Import(utcNowMethodInfo )`

Is there a way to import utcNow without using typeof?